# Python dulwich error when pulling

Tags: python, git, dulwich

When I try to pull a folder with dulwich, I got this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I got the same error on windows or linux.
The clone fonction works perfectly

Here is my code:

```
 from dulwich import porcelain
 import ssl

 depot_maj = "https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich.git"

 #Disable SSL verification for private server
 ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


 #porcelain.clone(depot_maj, "test")
 porcelain.pull("test", depot_maj)
```

When i change the pull fonction with this:

```
 porcelain.pull("test", depot_maj, "refs/heads/master")
```

I got:

```
 TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

EDIT: Im running Python 3.5

Comment: You are probably running under Python 2. At the beginning of the file, add [`from __future__ import unicode_literals`](http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html) to the beginning of the file and see if the issue goes away.  If you are on Python 3, it's probably due to some internal API incomplete migration to Python 3.

Comment: I'm running Python 3

Comment: Looks like an internal bug in Dulwich as it isn't fully Python 3 compatible.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've created an issue on the repo of Dulwich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW this issue is fixed in newer versions of Dulwich.